# Change background-color md-tooltip

Tags: html, css, angularjs

how can i change background-color md-tooltip :

**HTML**

```
    <md-tooltip md-direction="right" class="tooltip">ssssssss</md-tooltip>
```

**CSS**

```
.tooltip{
text-align: left;
top: -1px;
left: 50px!important;
width: 176px;
height: 41px !important;
line-height: 38px;
padding-left: 12px;
border: 1px solid;
opacity: 100;
background-color: #f1f5f9;
border-color: #A4C6DD;
```

}
when i Add "!important" to background-color in properties but it not change 
how can change it

Comment: Try adding more specificity to your selector, ie: `md-tooltip.tooltip`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use background property instead of background-color

Hope it will help you.

```
For example

.tooltip{background: black}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use class "tooltip-inner" and add background color to it. I hope that helps.